# Can anyone give the hint to find $\int_{|z|=3}\frac{dz}{(z^{2017}-1)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{|z|=3}\frac{dz}{(z^{2017}-1)}$.

How I can find this integral value? I tried with residue theorem (since there is an only one simple pole $z=1$ which is lie inside the circle $|z|=3$ ) but I'm not unable to find the residue at $z=1$. 
Can anyone help to find out this ? Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 3):

The residue at $1$ is $\lim_z\to 1 \frac {z-1} {z^{2017}-1}=\lim_{z\to 1} \frac 1 {2017z^{2016}}$ by L'Hopital's Rule. But remember that there are 2017 poles inside $|z|=3$ (namely the $2017-$ th roots of unity. You have to take all these poles into consideration.

Comment: I know this , but how can I will confirm which  2017th roots of unity lies inside the circle $|z|=3$.

Comment: @Sachin The $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity can be also written in the form $\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi k}n\right)$ where $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$. Recall that every complex number can be written as $z=r\exp(it)$ you may notice that $r=1$ *for all* roots of unity since the radius is *not* affected by $k$. Thus, *all* roots of unity, regardless of what order, lie on the unit cirle, i.e. the circle given by $|z|=1$ which is obviously within the circle $|z|=3$. Therefore you have to consider all so occuring poles; not only the one at $z=1$.

Comment: Yep , this was the basic things .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use that the sum of all residues including the residue at $\infty$ is $0$:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=3}\frac{dz}{(z^{2017}-1)} = -\operatorname{Res}_{z=\infty}\frac{1}{z^{2017}-1} =  \operatorname{Res}_{w=0}\frac{1}{w^2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{(w^2)^{2017}}-1}$$ 
$$  =\operatorname{Res}_{w=0}\frac{z^{4032}}{1-z^{4034}}= 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is much simpler to consider singularities of the function *outside* the integration contour.

> The integrand has no singularities outside the circle $|z|=3$. Residue at infinity is $$\operatorname { Res }  (f(z),\infty)=-\operatorname { Res }  \left(\frac1 {z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right),0\right)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac {z^{2015}}{z^{2017}-1}=0.$$ Therefore  $$\int_{|z|=3}\frac{dz}{z^{2017}-1}=0.$$

Comment: $1/z$ also tends to zero at infinity. We want a zero of an order higher than one, say, of order 2017 :).

Comment: @Maxim Thanks. Corrected.